# How do I search this? Possible to access more than 100 JSON api search results if I pay for it?

Tags: google-custom-search

How to search this?

I want to be able to:

```
1. create a search engine
2. programatically search it thorugh an API (python, or other)
3. paginate through the results (all of them, if I chose)
4. store URL's or results that I want.
```

Is this even possible with Google Custom Search Engine?

I enabled billing, my CC is up to date with Google, I do steps 1..3 above.

On a search, I will get back 4,000 results for example, but I can only access 10 at a time with the API, none more, and when I reach 100 results I am shut off.

I want to be able to process 1000 results if I wish.

Before you reply, do you personally have working code that goes beyond the 100 limit?

If so, would be very much interested in speaking, learning how you did it.

I am using Python at the moment, but it could be any language.

--

### I tried using the &start=100, 200, and so on to paginate through, but this does not work.

I tried getting 100 results in a python script, ending the program, calling it again setting start=100 (after the first set returned), and nothing happened.

I want to be able to use the Google Custom Search API, pay Google for a monthly subscription but have not found that this is possible.

For any given search, I want to decide how many results to process, could be 1K, could be 20K, I simply need/want access to the full result set, but I do not, have not seemed to find a way to do this.

Comment: Is there a way I can pay for more search results beyond 100?

Answer (score 1):

The API  allows only a max result depth of 100.  See https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list

Comment: Is there a way I can pay for more search results beyond 100?

Comment: Select this like the correct answer. @user10664542 you could use e.g. unnoficial python plugins but it is forbidden to scrape Google.